# Vertically align span with inline-block div > table

Tags: html, css

Given this unfortunate but required structure:

```
<span>Label Text</span>
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Single Row Table Text</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the given CSS:

```
span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

What is the correct way to style the span so that it appears to be vertically aligned with the div > table?

Here is a simple example of what I do not want: http://jsfiddle.net/itslittlejohn/3hLsy1yf/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set both `<span>` and `<div>` as inline block and vertical align middle.

```css
span, div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span>Label Text</span>
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Single Row Table Text</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Fiddle demo in case there are multiple table rows - http://jsfiddle.net/v4mh0r53/

Comment: Perfect. This one had me stumped, but it's so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you close to what you want?

```
  span{
     vertical-align: top;
     padding-top: 4px;
     display: inline-block;
  }
```

This may not work in a context where there is more content or there are other factors involved. If there are more elements that would affect the position of the span and/or table could you post that code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this style

```
span {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    float: left;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5nx4m9h/)

Comment: Why do you need to set the display on the span if you're floating it?

Comment: @j08691 it can be removed, I forgot it because I tested it without floating first